# Activity Will Get Get Destroyed and Turn Back To Main Activity Error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android, android-studio, base64, encode

So I've been looking around stackoverflow + reddit + docs and still no solution about this, I've tried so many catch blocks but no clue I tried with bytearray but still the same problem. this was the error:

```
ERROR """  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.namecompany.nameoftheapp, PID: NOOFPID
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bad base-64
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:161)
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
        at com.nameoftheapp.company.EncryptDecrypt$2.onClick(EncryptDecrypt.java:56)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) """ ERROR
```

'''
**Code: '''
try {

```
                encode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        encode.setText(Base64.encodeToString(inputText.getText().toString().getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
                    }
                });


                decode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        decode.setText(new String(Base64.decode(inputText.getText().toString(), Base64.DEFAULT)));

                    }
                });

            }
           
            catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(EncryptDecrypt.this,"Numbers Cannot Be Decoded!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }        ''''code** '''
```

UPDATE:::::  While Testing the encoding part was fine , but sometimes the decoding would completely get out the class/activity and would get to the main and show me the error above the code:::: UPDATE

If you have any solution or inteffered with this problem before please lmk. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the structure of your try/catch block. You have something that is shaped like this:

```
try {
    encode.setOnClickListener(...);
    decode.setOnClickListener(...);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
}
```

This will only catch exceptions thrown while setting the listeners. It will not have any effect on exceptions thrown from *inside* the listeners.

Try this instead:

```
decode.setOnClickListener(
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            decode.setText(...);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // show toast message here
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, I'm totally newbie and stackoverflow community is a great one!!!! man, I've been trying for 3 days to fix this. Thanks ** 100